# Read and write IOS "Localizable_ios.strings" file using C#?

Tags: c#

strings file. Is there any way to read key and value using C#

Example:

"welcome" =           "Welcome    ";
"title_diary_1"         = "Diary";

Comment: Use collections such as Dictionary. If you can be still brief what you are trying and tried.

Comment: I have tried but not used. I have only one option to ready line by line and find the key and value.